# Alternative to logistic regression - effect of a covariate

Tags: logistic, modeling

I have a data set with one binary response variable $Y$, and three categorical covariates $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$. I want to find out what effect $X_1$ has on $Y$ (and if the effect is significant). Naturally, I solve this by fitting a logistic regression model (using all three covariates), and analyse the table of deviance.

Are there any alternative methods to solve this problem?

I'm aware of the classification methods mentioned here [Alternatives to logistic regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/alternatives-to-logistic-regression-in-r), but my problem doesn't concern prediction.

Comment: What kind of alternative are you looking for AND/OR What kind of information other than odds ratios and p-values for significance are you looking for?

Comment: You can use a binomial glm with some other link function,  to say more than this we need detail of your application.

Comment: Essentially, I would like to know if there is a relation between $Y$ and $X_1$, given $X_2$ and $X_3$. This is a homework assignment, and I don't think I can be any more specific. So far, I've done some basic plotting as part of the EDA, and looked at pairwise correlations.

Comment: Have you considered interactions?

Comment: Do you mean interaction terms in the logistic regression model, such as $X_1 * X_2$? If so, yes. I understand my question lacks details, which makes it hard to answer, but to be clear; I would like to know if there's any other method than regression I could use in assessing the relation between two categorical variables $Y$ and $X_1$.